# Keep path while redirecting to another domain with haproxy

Tags: redirect, haproxy

Good day!

I am hosting a web site https://one.com, a user access the site with a sub-path https://one.com/anything, i need to redirect the user to another domain but to keep the sub-path https://two.com/anything

The problem that the sub-path "anything" is not static, literally anything can be the sub-path.

Cant share the config because i could not even remotely achieve any success in this question.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, i meant: "how to do that kind of redirect"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not clear.  What "kind of redirect" do you mean?  It would be helpful if you edit the question to include your current `haproxy.cfg` and an example of what you *do* want to happen, rather than URLs which are *not* representative of your issue.

That said, you might be looking for something like this:

```
http-request redirect code 301 location https://two.com%[capture.req.uri] if { hdr_dom(host) -m end one.com }
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, edited the post for more clarity.

Comment: And, yes, this is exactly what i was looking for! Worked like a charm!! Thank you very much!